# ASPX Calendar Keep Session["SelectedDates"]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a calendar that can select multiple dates in ASP. The problem is that upon changing to a different month, the Session["SelectedDates"] will be empty (presumably because the previous dates are not in view). This prevents me from selecting multiple dates from multiple months as the dates from the other months will be cleared. How can I fix this problem?

I have been trying store the dates in a temp var during OnVisibleMonthChanged, but I can't get the code to work right.

```
private List<DateTime> datelist = new List<DateTime>();

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
    {
        List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];

        foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
        {
            if (Calendar1.SelectedDates.Contains(dt))
            {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Remove(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt);
            }
        }
        datelist.Clear();
    }
}

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
    {
        datelist.Add(e.Day.Date);
    }
    Session["SelectedDates"] = datelist;
}
```

ASPX

```
                                    <asp:Calendar NextPrevStyle-ForeColor="White" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Calendar1" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged"
                                        runat="server" BorderWidth="1px"
                                        DayNameFormat="Shortest">
                                    </asp:Calendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to handle this problem was to use ViewState.  I modified the code from https://sdevireddy.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/multiple-date-selection-in-asp-calendar/ . I transfer the ViewState to the Session whenever the selection is changed. The dates can then be obtained from the session.

```
public List<DateTime> SelectedDates
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["Dates"] != null)
            return (List<DateTime>)ViewState["Dates"];
        else
            return new List<DateTime>() { Calendar1.SelectedDate };
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Dates"] = value;
    }
}

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DateTime selectedDate in Calendar1.SelectedDates)
    {
        if (SelectedDates.Contains(selectedDate))
            SelectedDates.Remove(selectedDate);
        else
            SelectedDates.Add(selectedDate);
    }

    ViewState["Dates"] = SelectedDates;
    Session["SelectedDates"] = ViewState["Dates"];
}

protected void Calendar1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear();
    foreach (DateTime dt in SelectedDates)
        Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the postback is not well handled in you're calendar, because when you choose any date in your calendar the **Calendar1_DayRender** is called and set the **datelist** to null, thus the session will be filled with null, so in **Calendar1_SelectionChanged** the result of the session will return *NULL*. You can check by adding a breakpoint on the **Calendar1_DayRender** function and moniter it's actions.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it is working to select multiple dates across months. Make sure both events are linked up.

```
public static List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();

    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
        {
            dateList.Add(e.Day.Date);
        }
        Session["SelectedDates"] = dateList;
    }


    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
        {
            List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
            foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
            {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt);
            }
            dateList.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This has the same problem. If you click a date on say Jan, click another date on March, the selected date at Jan will be gone.

Comment: Can you post your aspx code for the calendar? Do you have other code anywhere that could mess with the postback?

Comment: When I run all the code in your post I get the same issue you have, when I run the code I posted it is keeping the dates across the months. I can't immediately spot where the issue in your code is but will have a proper look through. Have you tried changing all the code to the code I posted?

Comment: The only difference I noticed was your datelist is Public and static. Perharps thats the issue.

Comment: I've just given it a test, you just need a static on your datelist and it will keep the dates between months

Comment: I will test it tomorrow on my side. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this, it may be useful:

```
protected void C1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
        L1.Items.Add(C1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());

        ListItem[] x = new ListItem[L1.Items.Count];
        L1.Items.CopyTo(x, 0);
        Session["x"] = x;
        ListItem[] collection = (ListItem[])Session["x"];
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {

            Label1.Text += item.Text + "</br>";
        }
    }
```

And anthore way You make try this:

```
List<DateTime> lb = new List<DateTime>();
        lb.Add(C1.SelectedDate);
        DateTime[] a = lb.ToArray();
        lb.CopyTo(a, 0);
        Session["x"] = a;
        DateTime[] collection = (DateTime[])Session["x"];
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            Label1.Text += item.ToShortDateString() + "</br>";
        }
```